# Empty sqlite database when app send on another device

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing Android app and I have SQLite database in it. I have inserted records in database. Now when I am sending my app into another device there is empty database!. Please help me

public void createPrincipal(CollegePrincipal principal){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(PRINCI_NAME, principal.getName());
    values.put(PRINCI_QUALI, principal.getQalification());
    values.put(PRINCI_INTRO, principal.getIntro());

    // insert row
    long princi_id = db.insert(TABLE_PRINCI, null, values);

    Log.e("princi id", String.valueOf(princi_id));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when i sending my app into another device"? How are you sending?

Comment: hey @sagar can you Add your database query

Comment: When i seding my app to my friend via blutooth.

Comment: Just dump your data in table(s) and put your db in assets folder.To copy existing database refer http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Thank u Hiren Dabhi looks it can work thank u

Answer (score 0):

when ever you create data base it will in the local store of your device , And when you transfer app it wont care you local data you need store those data variables in you code to get in the another device.

Comment: Please tell me what should i do then

Comment: Now i need to insert thousand of records for my app in sqlite. How i can do this. If i inserted them in my app will this records be visible on all other devices.